# What's the default value to ModelBuilder and DbContextOptionsBuilder?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Currently studying about .Net Core and Entity Framework Core, I'm learning about DbContext... And I understood that:

1. We usually use the **DbContextOptionsBuilder** to provide the *DbContextOptions* to the base of the context constructor, that's the **DbContext** builder, right?!
2. And we might also have some class configured to provide a custom model to the  **modelBuilder.Entity**, inside a *OnModelCreating* override

I'm almost ok about this topic and just curiouse to know, is there any default value and/or config for those params?

Comment: There isn't. Default Model is empty, and there's no default configuration. Try using an unconfigured DbContext, and you'll get an error asking you to configure it.

Comment: It's only a *builder*. It won't build anything if you don't give it anything. For example, `StringBuilder` doesn't have a default either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no its not default value or config on it.
you can see this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L468) .

OnModelCreating method by Default is Empty and you can delete this line of code in your OnModelCreating Method.

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

but if you use Identity,and your DbContext Class Inherit from IdentityDbContext, you should set that line in your OnModelCreating because its have default config.
you can see this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs#L358) for see configs .